# JQuery Chained data not showing in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, chained

I have written a `JQuery` cascade chain dropdown code in laravel. The code works properly when I run it with JSFiddle.

Please look at my code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80zkodod/32/)

**And the problem is this:**
[image]

The dropdown just does not appear. Please help!

Comment: I have edited my question. Please look again.

Comment: It is working in my browser. Are you seeing any  error in your browser console? Can you please see?